# Hide the fieldproperty if the related textfield contains no content

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, page-layout

I have a SharePoint 2013 page layout which contains some info in the footer area like so.

[image]

As you can see i have no content in the Regions yet the label is still appearing i would like to this to NOT display if there is not content.

I am using the following code in my page layout.

```
    <div class="tags">
    <strong><SharePointWebControls:FieldProperty FieldName="Regions" PropertyName="Title" runat="server" /> </strong>
    <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="Regions" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>      
    </div>
```

Comment: You can do this easily using JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hide the elements with javascript or jQuery like so:

```
function hideProperty(){        
    var x = document.getElementById('Label');   
    var d = document.getElementById('Label').parentNode.parentNode;
    if (x.value != ''){
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{       
        d.style.display = '';   
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I had several elements on the page I needed to hide?

Comment: Use a class selector in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, decided to go with Angular method. Works really well and can be applied.

```
    <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel PageDisplayMode="Display" ID="EditModePanel5" runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit">
     <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('Empty', []).controller('EmptyController', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element){
       angular.element($element).text().trim() != "" ? angular.element($element).parent().show() : angular.element($element).parent().remove();
      }]);
     </script>
    </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Then on the field elements themselves

```
       <div class="tags" data-ng-app="Empty">
                    <div class="qin-label" id="inputFormController">
                        <strong><SharePointWebControls:FieldProperty FieldName="Regions" PropertyName="Title" runat="server" />: </strong>
       </div>
                    <div data-ng-controller="EmptyController">
                        <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="Regions" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>  
                    </div>  
       </div>
```

Works perfectly, big shout out to Cas van Iersel who came up with the solution, full article can be seen here...[Hide empty fields on a SharePoint 2013 Page Layout](http://www.casvaniersel.com/2014/10/hide-empty-fields-on-a-sharepoint-2013-page-layout/#comment-35830)